# Adding a box around a caption in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a horizontal bar graph with a label centered below the x-axis. The closest I have gotten is adding a caption and centering it.
For a toy example to see what I mean:

```
library(ggplot2)
data("iris")

df <- as.data.frame(data("iris"))
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") + 
  labs(caption = "Add box around me", hjust = 0.5) +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = -3))+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Except there would be a box around the text at the bottom.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to switch to `ggtext::element_markdown` which has a lot more options than `element_text` and allows to for an outline:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

df <- as.data.frame(data("iris"))
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
  labs(caption = "Add box around me") +
  theme(
    plot.caption = ggtext::element_markdown(
      hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0, 
      box.color = "red",
      linewidth = .5, linetype = 1,
      padding = unit(5, "pt"),
      margin = margin(t = 20)
    )
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

And if you don't want to use the caption to add your annotation then a second approach - inspired by @TarJae's approach using `geom_label` - would be to use `annotation_custom` which in contrast to `geom_label` allows for a  more exact placement of the label and less fiddling to set the x and y position. Here we also have to set `clip="off"` and additionally make some space for the annotation which I achieved by increasing the bottom margin of the axis title.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
  annotation_custom(
    ggplot2:::labelGrob(
      label = "Add box around me",
      x = unit(.5, "npc"),
      y = unit(0, "npc") - unit(50, "pt"),
      padding = unit(5, "pt"),
      text.gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 8),
      rect.gp = grid::gpar(fill = NA, col = "red")
    )
  ) +
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(
      margin = margin(b = 50)
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using `geom_label` and using `clip = "off"`:

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  geom_label(
  label = "Add a box around me", 
  x = .05, 
  y = 1.25, 
  label.padding = unit(0.45, "lines"),
  label.size = 0.35,
  color = "black",
  fill = "white")+
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1,1,3.5,1.2, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thought about that route too but instead would have used `annotation_custom` for more robust and data independent placement of the label. See the second approach I just added.